# Angular: $sce is not working with ng v1.4.8

Tags: angularjs

my code is working fine when i am using ng version v1.2.1 but when i change version v1.4.8 then $sce is not working.

### small snippet

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
      .filter('customFilter', function ($sce) {
            return function (number) {
                if (isNaN(number) || number > 1) {
                    return number;
                } else {
                    if (number === 1) {
                        return $sce.trustAsHtml("&#x2714;");
                    } else if (number === 0) {
                        return $sce.trustAsHtml("&#x2718;");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

**see jsfiddle for full code** http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/jp6oq2tp/6/

guide me what to add in code when working with ng v1.4.8 as a result $sec should work. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$sce` supported by v1.4.8. for more info [click here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/docs/api/ng/service/$sce)

try this, updated from your fiddle

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    app.controller("HelloCntl", function ($scope) {
$scope.friends = [
    {
    name: 0,
    phone: '555-1276'},
{
    name: 0,
    phone: '800-BIG-MARY'},
{
    name: 1,
    phone: '555-4321'},
{
    name: 2,
    phone: '555-5678'},
{
    name: 2,
    phone: '555-8765'}
];
})
app.filter('customFilter', function ($sce) {
        return function (number) {
            if (isNaN(number) || number > 1) {
                return number;
            } else {
                if (number === 1) {
                    return $sce.trustAsHtml("&#x2714;");
                } else if (number === 0) {
                    return $sce.trustAsHtml("&#x2718;");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: you were not defined HelloCntl as controller

Answer (score 1):

Just added controller correctly. It should be like -

```
myApp.controller("HelloCntl", function ($scope) {

});
```

Please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jp6oq2tp/9/) if it works.

Comment: Controller defind in the fiddle provided by Monojit Sarkar was not in correct format.